# Why can't i input second number (num2) when i input first one as alphabet?

Tags: c, addition

/*program to add two integers and if input is not integer print invalid output*/

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
int num1,num2,flag=0,sum;
char chek,chek2;

/* To check input value a integer or not*/

if(scanf("%d%c", &num1, &chek);!= 2 || chek != '\n')
  { 
      flag=flag+1;

  }  
if(scanf("%d%c", &num2, &chek2) != 2 || chek2 != '\n')
   { 
       flag=flag+1;

   }   
if(flag!=0)
    printf("invalid input\n");
else
 { 
     sum=num1+num2;
     printf("the sum is:%d",sum);
 }
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: `scanf("%d%c", &num1, &chek);!= 2` won't compile. Also, your indentations is hideous (unless you're a Glibc programmer), and `flag` is a bad name for a variable.

Comment: "when i input first one as alphabet?"  --> post your input used.

Comment: "Why can't i input second number (num2) when i input first one as alphabet?" `scanf("%d%c", &num1, &chek)`  always expects (and requires) the first input to be parseable as an integer. If the input does not have that then it will not be consumed and the second `scanf` will then try to parse the same input and fail again in the same way.

Comment: please consistently indent the code.  Then it would be ever so much easier to read/understand

Answer (score 0):

`scanf` function return the number of items read, or in easier words, the items assigned to your format string.

If you input a character the first scanf will return 0 because is expecting to match a number and that if statement is executed immediately. When it hits the next scanf there is still data in the stdin because the initial character was no matched by the first scanf so it will also make the second one to return 0. That's why you get the message printed after the first input.

If you always want to input the second number even if the first was not valid you need to make sure that you clear the stdin buffer so it can block in the second scarf and wait for you to input new data. There is a function called fflush that you can call like this `fflush(stdin)` but it's behavior is quite undefined and you should not rely on it for anything.

I will post your code with a little hack to make the program work with the expected behavior.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    int num1,num2,flag=0,sum;
    char chek,chek2;


    if( scanf("%d%c", &num1, &chek) != 2 || chek != '\n')
    {
        flag = flag + 1;

        //Ugly hack to clear the stin buffer
        char ch;
        while ((ch = getchar()) != EOF && ch != '\n');

    }

    if( scanf("%d%c", &num2, &chek2) != 2 || chek2 != '\n')
    {
        flag = flag + 1;
    }

    if(flag!=0) {
        printf("invalid input\n");
    } else {
        sum = num1 + num2;
        printf("the sum is:%d\n", sum);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

What I've done is to try to read everything from the stdin until I find a new line or an end-of-file. This way the buffer is empty and the next scanf will not try to match any remaining data from your last input.